# Batch script to move files into a zip

Tags: bash, unix, recursion, zip, directory

Is anybody able to point me in the right direction for writing a batch script for a UNIX shell to move files into a zip one at at time and then delete the original.

I cant use the standard zip function because i don't have enough space to fit the zip being created.

So any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution but simple, i ended up finding a python script that recursively zips a folder and just added a line to delete the file after it is added to the zip

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
zip -r -m source.zip *
```

Comment: I had already tried something like that, from the docs

"""
-m
    Move the specified files into the zip archive; actually, this deletes the target directories/files after making the specified zip archive. If a directory becomes empty after removal of the files, the directory is also removed. No deletions are done until zip has created the archive without error. This is useful for conserving disk space, but is potentially dangerous so it is recommended to use it in combination with -T to test the archive before removing all input files. """

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `find` as

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 zip -m archive
```

This will move every file into the zip preserving the directory structure. You are then left with empty directories that you can easily remove. Moreover using `find` gives you a lot of freedom on what files you want to compress.

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
zip --move destination.zip src_file1 src_file2
```

Here the detail of "--move" option from the man pages

> --move
>
> Move  the  specified files into the zip archive; actually, this
> deletes the target directories/files after making the specified zip
> archive. If a directory becomes empty after removal of the files, the
> directory  is  also  removed.  No deletions are done until zip has
> created the archive without error.  This is useful for conserving disk
> space, but is potentially dangerous so it is recommended to use it in
> combination with -T to test the archive before  removing  all input
> files.

Comment: This is the same as the answer above and has the same issue where the deletion is only after the zip has been fully created.